How to transitively "import" a conftest.py file?
I have a directory structure with 1 base class, 1 test file, and 2 conftest.py files, like so:
/tests/base/BUILD

  py_library(
    name="some_base",
    srcs=["some_base.py"]
  )

/tests/base/conftest.py

  import pytest
  @pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
  def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    result = outcome.get_result()
    setattr(item, "result_" + result.when, result)

/tests/base/some_base.py

  class SomeBase:
    ...

/tests/BUILD

  py_test(
    name="some_test",
    srcs=["some_test.py"],
    deps=["//tests/base:some_base"]
  )

/tests/conftest.py

  # empty content

/tests/some_test.py

  import tests.base.some_base
  class SomeTest(some_base.BaseClass):
    ...




At runtime (pytest some_test...), it fails in a way that demonstrates that pytest_runtest_makereport was never processed by pytest. If I amend /tests/conftest.py like so, it works:
/tests/conftest.py

  import tests.base.conftest
  pytest_runtest_makereport = conftest.pytest_runtest_makereport

Any chance there's a cleaner way to get pytest to process the conftest.py files transitively depended upon by the test?
(I've read through a bunch of related SO questions (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=conftest.py), but haven't quite landed on this use case).
